# How can I show the tabcontent of a same id after using a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, hyperlink

I have translated my site into several languages. Each translation of a page is a `div` with the same `id`. The language to be displayed is selected by Javascript (see code) via a button.

I already tried to implement cookies, but failed fatally (nothing was displayed anymore).
Now I want to save the selected language as a cookie, so that after using a link to another page of my website the same language is displayed immediately.

````
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(langName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

  document.getElementById("index").click();```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as well to achieve this.

Example:

```js
// getting the current language with English as a fallback
var language = window.localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'en'

// ... your code for setting the language ...

// setting the selected language
window.localStorage.setItem('lang', language)
```